# Check if a value is equal to a given values

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm trying to check if one of the pixel values exist in the image and tried it a lot with zero results:

```
if value or value2 or value3 or value4 == (248, 64, 64)or(250, 64, 64)or(83, 159, 254)or(255,255,255):
    print(value),print(value2),print(value3),print(value4)
```

It gives me this output:

```
(0, 33, 66)
(167, 126, 101)
(152, 178, 82)
(239, 174, 67)
```

Comment: yeah @Carcigenicate

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest storing values and colors in lists and check with the `in` operator.

```py
values = [
    value,
    value2,
    value3,
    value4
]
colors = [
    (248, 64, 64),
    (250, 64, 64),
    (83, 159, 254),
    (255, 255, 255)
]

if any(v in colors for v in values):
    for v in values:
        print(v)
```

But if you want to check the whole image, depending on the way images are represented, you should be able to check if color exists in the image without iterating manually through each pixel.

For example, if it is 2D NumPy array of tuples:

```
if any(np.any(image == c) for c in colors):
    ...
```

could be the solution.

Comment: first solution comes with output "too many values to unpack", please tell me how use the second one

Comment: The first solution works for me. Check if you copied it correctly.